# Update created date from Data Loader or DBAmp

Tags: data-loader, dbamp

I'm migrating data over from another CRM.

The person who did it didn't populate the correct Created Dates for our contacts, so another field was created that does have the correct created date.

Am I able to update that date with the correct date?

I have "Create Audit Fields" option turned on but cannot get the dates to update with a tool like Data Loader or DBAmp

Answer (score 0):

According to this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331038&type=1&mode=1) and this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZG_z6PGqfs) you can only set the audit fields (e.g. CreatedByID, CreatedDate, LastModifiedbyID, LastModifiedDateon) on create, not update. So your best bet would be to delete the contact records from your org and reimport them again via dataloader. You will need 'Create Audit Fields' and 'Modify All Data' permission to set audit fields via the api.